# dplyr summarise() with special functions for edge cases

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to make a groupwise `summarise()` operation in dplyr, but where a different function applies if edge cases are met.

I have count data that looks like this. The concentration and the standard deviation are calculated like this:

```
library(dplyr)
testdata <- data_frame(sample = sort(rep(1:3, 4)),
                   volume = rep(c(1e-1, 1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-2), 3),
                   count = c(400, 400, 40, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 400, 400, 400))

testdata %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  summarise(concentration = sum(count) / sum(volume),
            sd   = sqrt(sum(count)))
```

However, when making the calculation only counts with values between 25-250 are to be included. which I could achieve with:

```
testdata %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>%
  filter((count >= 25) & (count <= 250)) %>%
  summarise(concentration = sum(count) / sum(volume),
            sd   = sqrt(sum(count)))
```

But then samples 2 & 3 have no concentration.

The edge cases for each group might be calculated with something like:

```
if (all(count <= 25)){
  summarise(concentration = 25 / min(volume),
            sd = NA)
}
else if (all(count >= 250)){
  summarise(concentration = 250 / max(volume),
            sd = NA)
}
```

Can such edge cases be integrated into the `summarise()` function?

I would ideally also like a flag to indicate an edge case which returns result = "OK" for all cases except edge cases that return:

```
if (all(count <= 25)){
  summarise(concentration = 25 / min(volume),
            sd = NA,
            result = "LOW")
}
else if (all(count >= 250)){
  summarise(concentration = 250 / max(volume),
            sd = NA,
            result = "HIGH")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to encode your logic within `summarise` using `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- testdata %>% group_by(sample) %>%
                       summarise(concentration = ifelse(all(count <= 25), 
                                                        25 / min(volume),
                                                        ifelse(all(count >= 250), 
                                                               250 / max(volume), 
                                                               sum(count) / sum(volume))),
                                 sd = ifelse(all(count <= 25), 
                                             NA, 
                                             ifelse(all(count >= 250), 
                                                    NA, 
                                                    sqrt(sum(count)))),
                                 result = ifelse(all(count <= 25), 
                                                 "LOW", 
                                                 ifelse(all(count >= 250),
                                                        "HIGH", 
                                                        "OK")))
print(result)
### A tibble: 3 x 4
##  sample concentration       sd result
##   <int>         <dbl>    <dbl>  <chr>
##1      1          4000 29.66479     OK
##2      2          2500       NA    LOW
##3      3          2500       NA   HIGH
```

---

#### Updated approach

Another approach, which is hopefully closer to what the OP asks, is to define a function:

```
summarise.func <- function(count, volume) {
  if (all(count <= 25)) {
    concentration <- 25 / min(volume)
    sd <- NA
    result <- "LOW"
  } else if (all(count >= 250)) {
    concentration <- 250 / max(volume)
    sd <- NA
    result <- "HIGH"
  } else {
    concentration <- sum(count) / sum(volume)
    sd <- sqrt(sum(count))
    result <- "OK"
  }
  data.frame(concentration=concentration, sd=sd, result=result, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

that handles both the regular case and the edge cases. The key is that this function return a `data.frame` containing the summarized results. Then, `summarise` will create a column that is a list containing these data frames that can then be `tidyr::unnest`ed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- testdata %>% group_by(sample) %>%
                       summarise(csr=list(f(count, volume))) %>%
                       unnest(csr)
print(result)
### A tibble: 3 x 4
##  sample concentration       sd result
##   <int>         <dbl>    <dbl>  <chr>
##1      1          4000 29.66479     OK
##2      2          2500       NA    LOW
##3      3          2500       NA   HIGH
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the question, so I am going to accept it. I guess I was looking for an answer that calculates the concentration/sd/result for each case separately instead of having the logic for each edge case nested within the logic for the calculation of each variable.

Comment: @Aaron: My suggestion then is to **not** accept the answer as is. That way, someone else (maybe even I) can provide another answer that would be better and acceptable.

Comment: no problem. But I think I might try another question and see if I can express this concept as a question more explicitly.

Comment: @Aaron: If you can, just edit this question. I'm going to think harder to see if I can get closer to what you want (I think I understand that). No promises, though. The problem in my mind is in mixing the grouping with the logic; we might try to do this outside of `dplyr`.

Comment: @Aaron: please see my update to see if it is closer to what you want.